# Вывод координат мыши QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, mouse-event, координаты

Есть задача: выводить координаты мыши (в системе координат одного из лэйблов). Однако ума каким образом это реализовать - не хватает. Находил схожие решения, однако не смог добавить их в свой код (почему-то мой Qt не понимает события mouse realised). Каким образом это можно реализовать в моем коде?

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_openFileBttn_clicked();

    void on_saveBttn_clicked();

    void on_goBttn_clicked();

    void on_radioButton_clicked();

    void on_SRfilterBttn_clicked();

    void on_adFilterBttn_clicked();

    void on_fildSizeSlider_rangeChanged(int min, int max);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QImage>
#include <QString>
#include "filters.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    centralWidget()->setMouseTracking(true);
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



bool filterType; //тип фильтра false - среднеарифметический, true - медианный
QImage picture;




void MainWindow::on_openFileBttn_clicked() //открыть файл
{

    ::picture.load(ui->lineEdit->text());//загружаем путь из текстового окна
    QPixmap pixmap(ui->lineEdit->text()); //создаем пиксмап
    ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);      //натягиваем сову на глобус
    ui->label->show();                 //
}

void MainWindow::on_saveBttn_clicked()
{
    ::picture.save(ui->lineEdit_2->text()); // сохраняем картинку по пути из 2 окна
    //сохранить результат
}

void MainWindow::on_goBttn_clicked()
{
    ui->label_5->setText("Выполняется");
    if (ui->SRfilterBttn->isChecked() != false || ui->radioButton->isChecked() != false)
    {
        ::picture = usefilters(::picture, ::filterType, ui->fildSizeSlider->value()); //применяем фильтр
        ::picture.save(ui->lineEdit_2->text()); // сохраняем картинку по пути из 2 окна
        QPixmap pixmap2(ui->lineEdit_2->text()); //создаем 2 пиксмап
        ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap2);      //натягиваем сову на глобус
        ui->label->show();                 //
        ui->label_5->setText("Готово!");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->label_5->setText("Ошибка!");
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_adFilterBttn_clicked()
{
    ::filterType = false;
    //выбран адаптивный фильтр
}

void MainWindow::on_fildSizeSlider_rangeChanged(int min, int max)
{

    ui->label_4->setText(QString(ui->fildSizeSlider->value()));
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_clicked()
{
    ::filterType = true;
    //выбран адаптивный усредняющий фильтр
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_pressed()
{
    ::filterType = true;
    //выбран адаптивный усредняющий фильтр
}

void MainWindow::on_SRfilterBttn_clicked()
{
    ::filterType = false; //выбран среднеарифметический
}
```

Comment: Покажите чего вы хотите добиться в целом?

Comment: копать сюда https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html

Answer (score 1):

Глобальную позицию мыши вы можете получить с помощью [QCursor::pos()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#pos), а чтобы перевести в относительные для виджета координаты [QWidget::mapFromGlobal(const QPoint &pos)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо перегрузить mouseReleaseEvent() в MainWindow. Объект QMouseEvent будет содержать координаты курсора относительно MainWindow [1].
Если необходимо получить координаты относительно другого виджета, то необходимо вычесть из координат курсора координаты виджета (например label). [2]

```
void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{  
   qDebug() << "real pos = " << event->pos(); // [1]
   qDebug() << "relative pos = " << event->pos() - ui->label->geometry().topLeft(); // [2]  
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: или *QWidget::mouseMoveEvent*?

Comment: @magrif, автор сказал, что у него не срабатывает mouse release.